# How to show in django cms breadcrumbs full path?

Tags: django, django-cms, breadcrumbs

Need your advice - how to show in breadcrumbs whole path to article or page?
I've got code:

```
{% for ance in ancestors %}
   <li>
       {% if not forloop.last %}
       <a href="{{ ance.get_absolute_url }}">{{ ance.get_menu_title }}</a>
    {% else %}
      <span class="active">{{ ance.get_menu_title }}</span>
    {% endif %}
   </li>
{% endfor %}
```

but it shows only "Home" and current page. How to modify it to show whole path in breadcrumbs?

I've found in file menu_tags.py something that could be a code that calls ancestors. At least there is a class ShowBreadcrumbs:

```
    class ShowBreadcrumb(InclusionTag):
    """
    Shows the breadcrumb from the node that has the same url as the current request

    - start level: after which level should the breadcrumb start? 0=home
    - template: template used to render the breadcrumb
    """
    name = 'show_breadcrumb'
    template = 'menu/dummy.html'

    options = Options(
        Argument('start_level', default=0, required=False),
        Argument('template', default='menu/breadcrumb.html', required=False),
        Argument('only_visible', default=True, required=False),
    )

    def get_context(self, context, start_level, template, only_visible):
        try:
            # If there's an exception (500), default context_processors may not be called.
            request = context['request']
        except KeyError:
            return {'template': 'cms/content.html'}
        if not (isinstance(start_level, int) or start_level.isdigit()):
            only_visible = template
            template = start_level
            start_level = 0
        try:
            only_visible = bool(int(only_visible))
        except:
            only_visible = bool(only_visible)
        ancestors = []
        nodes = menu_pool.get_nodes(request, breadcrumb=True)

        # Find home
        home = None
        root_url = unquote(reverse("pages-root"))
        home = next((node for node in nodes if node.get_absolute_url() == root_url), None)

        # Find selected
        selected = None
        selected = next((node for node in nodes if node.selected), None)

        if selected and selected != home:
            node = selected
            while node:
                if node.visible or not only_visible:
                    ancestors.append(node)
                node = node.parent
        if not ancestors or (ancestors and ancestors[-1] != home) and home:
            ancestors.append(home)
        ancestors.reverse()
        if len(ancestors) >= start_level:
            ancestors = ancestors[start_level:]
        else:
            ancestors = []
        context['ancestors'] = ancestors
        context['template'] = template
        return context


register.tag(ShowBreadcrumb)


def _raw_language_marker(language, lang_code):
    return language


def _native_language_marker(language, lang_code):
    with force_language(lang_code):
        return force_text(ugettext(language))


def _current_language_marker(language, lang_code):
    return force_text(ugettext(language))


def _short_language_marker(language, lang_code):
    return lang_code


MARKERS = {
    'raw': _raw_language_marker,
    'native': _native_language_marker,
    'current': _current_language_marker,
    'short': _short_language_marker,
}
```

Comment: What does the structure look like? Do you have `Home > Child Page > Current page` type thing?

Comment: Yes, for example: Home > About Me > My books, but shows only Home > My books.
The first and the last instances.

Comment: You might be better served to include, in your question, the code used to get the `ancestors` iterable.

Comment: Added code with breadcrumbs and ancestor description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the exact same breadcrumb template that I use to achieve this, so as long as your page structure is similar to;

```
Home
  Child
    Grandchild
  Child
    Grandchild
```

You just need to load that template with the menu tags like; `{% show_breadcrumb 0 "partials/breadcrumb.html" 0 %}`

The docs on the menu tags are [here](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/navigation.html)

Don't forget, that if you have any pages hidden from the menus, they won't display in the breadcrumbs either because they're created by the menu tags using the page tree.

Comment: Mine code is with that zeroes, but still don't loads :(

Comment: @StPavel you don't have any pages with the menu option turned off do you?

Comment: Are you talking abut pages which are hidden from navigation menu? If so, then yes, I've got such pages. Almost all pages are hidden form navigation menu.

Comment: You'll probably find that they are the pages not showing in your breadcrumbs then. The breadcrumbs are a menu so if you hide them from the menu, you can't use the menu tags to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for advices, especially makrsweb. I found out that the reason was that pages weren't linked to each other. I've got Home, My books, Book1, Book2 etc. as standalone pages, when I linked them, making structure looking like:

```
Home  
    |My Books 
             |Book1
             |Book2
             |...
```

(Parent with childs and grandchilds) everything started to works normally.
The problem was not in the code, but in my inattentiveness.